# dynamo db error on update expression using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

i need to update a list on my aws-dynamo database. i have created a table with partition key : email. then iam insert some email id to the table successfully. Now my table like this

### email

manaf1@gmail.com

manaf2@gmail.com

manaf3@gmail.com

Then, i tried to update the table with new key "details" and its value is a list. this is my code

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

var params =
    {
        TableName: "manaftable1",
        Key: { email: "manaf1@gmail.com" },
        UpdateExpression: "set #details = list_append (#details, :detailsinput)",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#details": "details"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":detailsinput":{ "id": "1","mob": "978956" }
        }
    };


var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

docClient.update(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    else
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

But i got error like this

```
{
  "message": "Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: list_append, operand type: M",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2016-10-26T11:04:60.756",
  "requestId": "SN0NPRHDFHUKBBJHOVI0DFHHRQNSO5AEMVJFFGHF9ASFHUAAJG",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 0
}
```

i need response like this after updation

column1 : email

column2 : details

> manaf1@gmail.com |
>   [{"id":"1","mob":"978956"},{"id":"2","mob":"767886"}]
>
> manaf2@gmail.com |

what is the issue related with my code?

Comment: Do you have `details` defined in the schema? Alternatively you can get the item from DDB, update it and then using `put` update it in DDB

Comment: i only define key email in schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `details` attribute is **NOT** present in the item, the update expression should have just `SET` without the list_append.

```
UpdateExpression : "SET #details = :details"
```

When the `details` attribute is **present** in the item and the new update needs to add additional elements in the list, then `list_append` can be used to add the new element to the list.

```
UpdateExpression : "set #details = list_append (#details, :details)"
```

Answer (score 2):

As AWS documentation for [`list_append` says](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html):

> The new element must be contained in a list, for example to add 2 to a
>   list, the operand would be [2]

So you need to append an array of objects, not just an object:

```
var params =
    {
        TableName: "manaftable1",
        Key: { email: "manaf1@gmail.com" },
        UpdateExpression: "set #details = list_append (#details, :detailsinput)",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#details": "details"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":detailsinput": [{ "id": "1","mob": "978956" }]
        }
    };
```

If the property does not exist in the object, you can use `if_not_exists` operand:

```
var params =
    {
        TableName: "manaftable1",
        Key: { email: "manaf1@gmail.com" },
        UpdateExpression: "set if_not_exists(#details, []) set #details = list_append (#details, :detailsinput)",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#details": "details"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":detailsinput": [{ "id": "1","mob": "978956" }]
        }
    };
```

Comment: it will produce error {
  "message": "The provided expression refers to an attribute that does not exist in the item",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2016-10-26T16:28:41.626Z",
  "requestId": "CAMLAN7JKISU9C7NSTKUPMHCDJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 0
}

Answer (score 2):

Use `list_append()` and `if_not_exists()` together to append to a potentially non-existent list column:

```
var params = {
  TableName: "manaftable1",
  Key: { email: "manaf1@gmail.com" },
  UpdateExpression: "set #details = list_append(if_not_exists(#details, :empty_list), :detailsinput)",
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    "#details": "details"
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":detailsinput": [{ "id": "1","mob": "978956" }],
    ":empty_list": []
  }
};
```